# How to create RAS phonebook entries using python on Windows 7?

Tags: python, windows, ras

I am using `win32ras` and `Python 3.1` on Windows 7.

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    win32ras.EditPhonebookEntry(0, None, "NewEntry")
pywintypes.error: (120, 'RasEditPhonebookEntry', 'This function is not supported on this system.')
```

Is there any other way I can do it? I can switch to `Python2.x` as well if any such library exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a phonebook entry, you can use [RasSetEntryProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377827%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: How do you use that form Python? Can you point at an example, please?